# How to fix the following error in Classification dataset MNIST :-

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I assigned mnist as:

```
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version = 1)
```

while exploring the MNIST dataset, after assigning:

```
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
```

I tried to grab an instance’s feature vector, reshape it to a 28×28 array,
before that I assigned:

```
some_digit = X[0]
```

I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\kanishk\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-348a6e96ae02> in <module>
----> 1 some_digit = X[0]

c:\users\kanishk\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\users\kanishk\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  Since you haven't provided either sufficient code nor the expected trace, we can't do much to help you.  Obviously, you have an argument with the Python run-time system: you claim that `X` is a sequence with integer indices; the RTS says otherwise.  Guess who wins?

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in `X` - error shows that there is no `0` in `X`. It seems it is pandas `DataFrame` and `X[0]` searchs column with number `0` but it doesn't have it . If you want to get row with number `0` then you may need `X.iloc[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `X` is `pandas.DataFrame` and in `DataFrame` code `X[0]` searchs column with name `0` but `X` doesn't have it.

If you want to get row with number `0` then you may need `X.iloc[0]`

---

**BTW:**

When I run

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
print(type(X), X.shape)  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (70000, 784)

some_digit = X[0]
print(type(some_digit), some_digit.shape)  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (784,)
```

then I get `X` as `numpy.array` and `X[0]` gives me expected value.

Maybe somewhere you converted `X` from `numpy.array` to `pandas.DataFrame` - and now you have to use different methods to access data.